# Django: Business logic inside the models?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to figure out the best place for putting these business logic rules, I guess.
I have a `Property` model and I can't seem to find the right place to place `.mark_property_as_active` function that sets the property as active and etc.

I have two solutions. The first one would be just to have this method in the `Property` model itself (can use a mixin):

```
def mark_as_active(self):
    self.is_draft = False
    self.is_paused = False
    self.published_at = False

    ...
```

Ant the second solution would be to create `services.py` in which, I would have this method:

```
def mark_property_as_active(property_id, property_plan_id):
    property = Property.objects.get(pk=property_id)

    now = timezone.now()
    property.is_draft = False
    property.is_paused = False
    property.published_at = now

    # Activate plan for property
    plan = PropertyPlan.objects.get(pk=property_plan_id)

    property.plan_id = plan.pk
    property.plan_expires_at = timezone.now() + datetime(days=plan.timestamp_days)

    property.save()
```

Can you guys please tell me the main difference between using these two and which of these would count as a good practice?

Comment: in the `services.py` case it would be better to use an `.update(...)` query rather than `.get()` followed by `.save()` ... the latter is liable to race conditions when concurrent requests try to update the same row, leading to lost changes

Comment: https://django-best-practices.readthedocs.io/en/latest/applications.html#models seems to advocate for the former approach, i.e. "fat" models with many methods for relevant business logic.  Personally on large and complex projects I would tend towards the latter approach, i.e. the repository pattern https://deviq.com/design-patterns/repository-pattern ...you might still have some common utility methods on the models, but the wider application code would use functions from the repository rather than constructing arbitrary ORM queries. But it's very subjective and depends on project size etc

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer! It was pretty obvious, but I've been working on a lot of things recently and really forgot about it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches have their own advantages depending on the specific requirements and design of your app:

1. Model property:

   - The `mark_as_active` is a method of the model and encapsulates the logic within the model itself; the advantage is that the logic is closely tied to the model, making it convenient and intuitive to use. It promotes a more object-oriented approach.
   - This solution works well if the activation logic is directly related to the internal state and behavior of the model. As an example, in this case you can easily take advantage of some Django features like the [@cached_property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property) decorator.
   - It keeps the code modular and reduces the need for additional services or external functions (you can always call the MyModel.mark_as_active method)
2. Separate module:

   - The activation logic is encapsulated in a separate service function and the business logic is separated from the model itself, promoting separation of logic.
   - The service function can be more reusable and can be used from different parts of your application if needed (for example it's easy to unit test).
   - It allows for more flexibility in terms of organizing and structuring your codebase and works well if the activation logic involves additional operations beyond the scope of your model, such as calling additional models or implementing other complex logic.

Considerations:

- If the activation logic is simple and closely tied to the internal state of your model, adding the method directly to the model (approach 1) can provide a clean and effective implementation.
- If the activation logic involves additional operations or requires interactions with other models or external services, separating it into a service function (approach 2) can provide better separation of logic and maintainability.

In practice, you can consider a hybrid approach, where you start with approach 1 and then refactor to approach 2 if the activation logic becomes more complex or the requirements change.

Comment: Thank you very much for so detailed answer. This actually boosts my confidence and I'll take a look at what's best for my case:)